# How to add chapters to ogg file?

Tags: ffmpeg, media, multimedia, ogg, oggvorbis

I am trying to add chapters to a ogg file containing vorbis audio.

From [this link](https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/10016) I copied the following ffmpeg command.

```
ffmpeg -threads auto -y -i in.ogg -i metadata_OGG.txt -map_metadata 1 -codec copy out_METADATA.ogg
```

My metadata_OGG.txt file is as given below.

```
CHAPTER00=00:00:00.000
CHAPTER00NAME=Chapter 01
CHAPTER01=00:00:05.000
CHAPTER01NAME=Chapter 02
CHAPTER02=00:00:10.000
CHAPTER02NAME=Chapter 03
```

I am getting the following error.

```
[ogg @ 00000000006d6900] Unsupported codec id in stream 0
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
```

But if i change `-codec copy` to `-acodec copy` there is no error in ffmpeg but the text file is converted to video. i.e. the output file will have a static video frame with the text of metadata_OGG.txt in it. Also, I observe the following log message during conversion.

```
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:0 (ansi (native) -> theora (libtheora))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
```

Anybody please tell me what is going wrong here?

Also, I would like to know what is the right way to add chapters to ogg. I searched for some tools also. I did not get any.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what worked for me using `ffmpeg` 4.3.1.

I have a **metadata file** which almost respects [`ffmpeg`'s metadata file format](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Metadata-1):

```
;FFMETADATA1
title=Evolution theory

[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=0
END=
title=Darwin's point of view

[CHAPTER]
TIMEBASE=1/1000
START=78880
END=
title=Genghis Khan's children
```

*Notice the file format requires an `END` time, but leaving it empty didn't bother in my case.*

Now **I add chapter information** to my opus/ogg file:

```
ffmpeg -i darwin.opus.ogg -i darwin_chapters.txt -map_metadata 1 -c copy darwin_withchapters.opus.ogg
```

*Note: if you want to overwrite existing chapter information from the file, you may need to add a `-map_chapters 1` parameter in the `ffmpeg` command line above.*

That creates the file `darwin_withchapters.opus.ogg`. I **check if chapter info has really been added** to the file:

```
opusinfo darwin_withchapters.opus.ogg
```

*You would use `ogginfo` for Ogg/Vorbis files.*

And here is the result (I removed a few irrelevant lines):

```
ENCODER=opusenc from opus-tools 0.1.10
ENCODER_OPTIONS=--bitrate 112
title=Evolution theory
CHAPTER000=00:00:00.000
CHAPTER000NAME=Darwin's point of view
CHAPTER001=00:01:19.880
CHAPTER001NAME=Genghis Khan's children
[...]
```

Here you go. `ffmpeg` did the conversion between its metadata file format to [the vorbis tag/comment chapter format](https://wiki.xiph.org/Chapter_Extension).

You could also directly write metadata in the Vorbis Chapter Extension [format](https://wiki.xiph.org/Chapter_Extension), and use the classic `vorbiscomment` tool, or other tools which allow editing of opus/ogg in-file tags.

Answer (score 1):

Opus has been mentioned here. I was trying to make `opusenc` from `opus-tools` add chapters when encoding and couldn’t find a command line example anywhere. Thanks to the hints in this thread I managed to figure it out, perhaps someone may find it helpful.

```
opusenc --comment "CHAPTER000=00:00:00.000" --comment "CHAPTER000NAME=Hello" --comment "CHAPTER001=01:23:45.678" --comment "CHAPTER001NAME=World" input.wav output.opus
```

The chapter key/value scheme is the aforementioned [Ogg/Matroska](https://wiki.xiph.org/Chapter_Extension) one. Of course, more metadata options like `--title, --artist` etc. can be added.

Using `ffmpeg` to add the chapters resulted in two problems for me: The artwork image in the ogg/opus input file was missing in the output file, and ffmpeg rejected empty `END` chapter times.

I did this on Windows 10 using

- `opusenc opus-tools 0.2-3-gf5f571b (using libopus 1.3)`
- `ffmpeg version 4.4.1-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev`
- `opusinfo`, MPC-HC (64-bit) v1.7.11 and VLC Media Player 3.0.14 Vetinari to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

For ffmpeg to work, the metadata file should have the following header.

```
;FFMETADATA1
```

I followed the steps given in [ffmpeg documentation for metadata](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Metadata-1).

**But the issue is not resolved completely.**

With the above steps I am able to add metadata to mp4, mkv and other container files but not to ogg files. I am not sure whether ffmpeg supports adding chapters to ogg files.